# Pickle.dump(obj) dumps two lists that conatain exactly the same values but dump file has a diffrent size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pickle

I'm creating the parallelization of software that is doing a bunch of independent calculations so that the institute is not taking 6 hours to calculate one run. These results are saved in a list of arrays. The array length is static. This list is then dumped with pickle.dump(obj).

The difference is the single-threaded on is the size of 6.5 KiB and the multi-threaded one is 20,4 KiB

Firstly:
I did my research and yes you should not use pickle, but University is University. I also tested my multi-threaded implementation, I did that for the last days, I even compared a smaller sample by hand to be sure, so I'm not helped when you commend that I should check my multi-threaded implementation.

Now what I did:
First, of comparing all elements, between the single and multi-threaded created list, they are the same. Comparing the length, shape, sys.getsizeof(obj) they are the same.
Then I had a look into the pickle.dump(obj), this chooses the protocol on its own so I tried to use the different protocols. I got different results, but not the smaller one I expected.

Lastly I tripe checked if I really dump only the list and yes only the list is dumped.

As written above one would expect the get the exact same dump file size for the exact same list, so why is this not happening?

Yes, I'm new here and don't get all the rules so please give proper feedback on how to improve the question.

Comment: Do you get the same lists when you unpickle both files? If they're not the same, there's a problem with your multithreaded code.

Comment: Yes, I unpickle them and get the same file.

Comment: Sounds weird, but that both lists end up being equal is all that matters, isn't it? I would blame this on the pickle implementation and move on. If you want to investigate this, you'd better come up with a [mcve].

Comment: Sadly it wasn't, because the bigger dump lead to a slow down in the next steps of the processing with confused me for a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is rather trivial...

I should have checked also the types of the elements in the arrays. During the coding part in the night I used numpy for partitioning the list with values for the calculation and forgot about it completely.

With a simple array.tolist() this problem was fixed.

Conclusion:
Even in python check your types!

Comment: Had a coffee brake and heard the colleges taking about a problem with python numpy types...